# Design paradigm for PyTorch - SSADM, OOD

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, pytorch

I have been developing a PyTorch model for a university project. In the thesis structure that the university has given me, they have mentioned a design paradigm. Structured systems analysis & design method and object-oriented design.

My question is that in Pytorch we have classes for the model, loss function, training, testing, and other classes like utils, Is that make the design paradigm of the project OOD? We have created objects for model and loss functions in the training class. just importing a util class to the training class makes an inheritance? The use of different classes for the model and the loss function and using them in training class can be called as abstraction?

Thank you!